# Opencart 3 TWIG: как правильно использовать оператор AND

Tags: twig, opencart3.x

Пытаюсь использовать оператор AND в TWIG в Opencart 3 и он не работает. Пожалуйста подскажите что я делаю не так.

Есть страница товара с атрибутами. Я хочу сделать условие, что если есть два атрибута с конкретным ID, чтобы срабатывало мое условие.

```
{% for attribute_group in attribute_groups %}
    {% for attribute in attribute_group.attribute %}
        {% if attribute.attribute_id == 2 and attribute.attribute_id == 3 %}
            First condition
        {% elseif attribute.attribute_id == 2 %}
            Second condition
        {% elseif attribute.attribute_id == 3 %}
            Third condition
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Вот пример на словах:

```
Если есть атрибут с id равным 2 и атрибут с id равным 3, то писать "Этаж/кол-во этажей"
Если есть атрибут с id равным 2 только, то писать "Этаж"
Если есть атрибут с id равным 3 только, то писать "Кол-во этажей"
```

Comment: А Вы можете объяснить, каким образом `attribute.attribute_id` одновременно может быть равен как 2 так и 3? Потому что в Вашем случае это не два атрибута, это один и тот же атрибут.

Comment: Может я не правильно условие составил. Мне нужно чтобы определяло, если в массиве есть атрибут id2 и атрибут id3 одновременно.

Comment: Просто уберите условие с AND. Два дальнейших условия, удовлетворяют Ваше требование.

Comment: Мне нужно три условия. Когда есть только один атрибут, только другой атрибут и когда есть они оба одновременно.

Comment: Вы перебираете массив циклом, в одной итерации у Вас есть только один атрибут и сравнивать Вы можете только с одним атрибутом. В этой итерации он может быть равен 2, через две итерации он может быть равен 3, это удовлетворяет Ваше условие потому что эти атрибуты в одном массиве. Атрибут не может быть равен и 2 и 3 в одной итерации. Вы же понимаете как работают циклы и что такое массив?

Comment: По всей видимости понимаю плохо и изначально шел не в ту сторону. Мне помогли на другой площадке. Правильный вариант опубликовал тут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогли на другой площадке. Я изначально не правильно понимал оператор AND, поэтому ничего не получалось. Правильный ответ получается такой:

```
{% set words = [] %}
{% for attribute_group in attribute_groups %}
    {% for attribute in attribute_group.attribute %}
        {% if attribute.attribute_id == 2  %}
            {% set words = words|merge(['Этаж',]) %}
        {% elseif attribute.attribute_id == 3  %}
            {% set words = words|merge(['Кол-вот этажей',]) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% if words|default  %}
    {{ words|join('/') }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Я же Вам так и написал во втором комментарии: "Просто уберите условие с AND. Два дальнейших условия, удовлетворяют Ваше требование.".

Comment: Здесь основа решения лежит в переменной words и как она задействована. Если бы я просто убрал AND, то не добился бы нужного результата.